# How can I use criteria "IsInstalled=1" with IupdateSession->QueryHistory within IUpdateSession COM interface.

Tags: visual-c++

**When I use the below code, it returns the collection including uninstalled updates**

```
HRESULT hr;
hr = pIupdateSession->QueryHistory( NULL,
                               startIndex,
                               count,
                               &pIupdateHistoryCol );
```

**When I use criteria "IsInstalled=1", it returns an error.**

BSTR criteria = SysAllocString(L"IsInstalled=1");

```
LONG startIndex = 0;
LONG count = 5;
if( criteria != NULL){
    hr = pIupdateSession->QueryHistory( criteria,
                               startIndex,
                               count,
                               &pIupdateHistoryCol );
    SysFreeString(criteria);
}
```

value of hr returned is -2145124302

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)